# Change inactive class active class and apply for selected element only

Tags: jquery

in given example I used class .inactive for not selected link element, I want to convert .inactive to .active and apply to active link element, means there will be only one .active in list.

HTML :

```
<div class="tab-header clearfix">
  <ul id="tabs">
    <li><a id="tab1">About the App</a></li>
    <li><a id="tab2">PLO</a></li>
    <li><a id="tab3">Prerequisites</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-container" id="tab1C">
  tab-container 1
</div>

<div class="tab-container" id="tab2C">
  tab-container 2
</div>

<div class="tab-container" id="tab3C">
  tab-container 3
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.tab-header {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
}
.tab-header #tabs {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
.tab-header #tabs li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  width: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tab-header #tabs li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: blue;
}
.tab-header #tabs li a.inactive {
  color: blue;
  background: white;
}
.tab-header .tab-container {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

jQuery :

```
$('#tabs li a:not(:first)').addClass('inactive');
                $('.tab-container').hide();
                $('.tab-container:first').show();

                $('#tabs li a').click(function(){
                    var t = $(this).attr('id');
                    if($(this).hasClass('inactive')){ //this is the start of our condition 
                    $('#tabs li a').addClass('inactive');           
                    $(this).removeClass('inactive');

                    $('.tab-container').hide();
                    $('#'+ t + 'C').fadeIn('slow');
                 }
                });
```

**[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/alpeshlahad/dtfbfqbd/3/)**

Comment: i dont see a question or problem on fiddle is this just a demo?

Comment: @guradio, if you inspect code then you will see ".inactive" class to anchor tag except not selected tab, I am about to appy ".active" tab to selected tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('#tabs li a').click(function(){
      var t = $(this).attr('id');

      if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){ //this is the start of our condition 

                    $('#tabs li a').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');           
                    $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');

                    $('.tab-container').hide();
                    $('#'+ t + 'C').fadeIn('slow');
                 }
                });
```

[https://jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/dtfbfqbd/5/)

Comment: @bp Thanks :), that is it

Comment: If I dont want inactive class and just active class then what will be the code, i want to remove existence of ".inactive" from code and css

Comment: Yes you need to remove the existence code "addClass('inactive')" and "removeClass('inactive')" . if this solved , then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this ?

When you click on some tab , this function will add `inactive` class to each tab that has no class `inactive`. Then, remove `active` class from all of them. Last, remove `inactive` class from tab you click and add it with active class

```
 $('#tabs li a').click(function(){
      var t = $(this).attr('id');
      $('#tabs li a').click(function(){
             $('#tabs li a:not(.inactive)').addClass("inactive");
             $('#tabs li a').removeClass("active");
             $(this).removeClass("inactive");
             $(this).addClass("active");
      });
 });
```